# Dynamic Type does not work with tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier:)

Tags: xcode, uitableview, autolayout, ios10, swift4

I'm experiencing a quite strange behaviour for my UITableViewCells with style .subtitle regarding Dynamic Type. When using

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "DesignElementCell", for: indexPath) //Dynamic Type does not work properly in this case
    cell.textLabel?.text = "Test"
    cell.detailTextLabel?.text = "Test"
    return cell
}
```

the output looks like

[image]

As you can see the header text is scaled fine, while cell labels are not. When using

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = UITableViewCell(style: .subtitle, reuseIdentifier: "DesignElementCell")
    cell.textLabel?.text = "Test"
    cell.detailTextLabel?.text = "Test"
    return cell
}
```

Everything works fine:

[image]

The strangest thing in the first case is, that when I change dynamic type size in settings and head back to my app, suddenly everything seems to work as long as I'm not popping my ViewController. Does anyone experienced something similar? Have a nice day :)

Answer (score 0):

First, check if you registered cell, and set delegate&dataSource of tableView in ViewDidLoad()

```
tableView.delegate = self
tableView.dataSource = self
tableView.register(Cell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier:"CellIdentifier")
```

Then, define rowHeight & estimatedRowHeight of tableView in ViewDidLoad()

```
tableView.rowHeight = UITableView.automaticDimension
tableView.estimatedRowHeight  = 150
```